# How to adjust this OpenGL codes of drawing a 2d circle into an ellipse

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this lines of codes that I used to draw circle but I wonder how can I adjust the codes so I would get an ellipse instead of a circle.

```
void circle(int n, int x, int y, int r) {
double inc = 2 * PI / (double)n;
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for (double theta = 0.0; theta <= 2 * PI; theta += inc) {
    glVertex2i(r * cos(theta) + x, r * sin(theta) + y);
}
glEnd(); }
```

Comment: e.g.: `glVertex2i(2 * r * cos(theta) + x, r * sin(theta) + y);`

Comment: thanks I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

The difference between an ellipse and a circle is just that one direction is longer than the other.

So instead of calculating `r*cos(theta)` and `r*sin(theta)` you could use a different `r` in each. An ellipse has a different "radius" in each direction.

Note that this will produce an axis-aligned (i.e. horizontal or vertical ellipse). To create an ellipse which is not axis-aligned (e.g. 45 degrees) it may be easier to start with an axis-aligned ellipse and rotate it using a rotation matrix.

Comment: Ouhhh I understand. Thanks, really helping!

Answer (score 0):

here is what i have:

```
void circle(int n, int x, int y, int rx, int ry) {
double inc = 2 * PI / (double)n;
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
for (double theta = 0.0; theta <= 2 * PI; theta += inc) {
    glVertex2i(rx * cos(theta) + x, ry * sin(theta) + y);
}
glEnd(); 
}
```